Can't recreate an object in .NET Winforms 4.8.1 C#
I'm trying to make a settings program for a project I'm working on, and I need a way to unload objects (specifically pictureboxes and labels). I probably will need the objects later, but I don't want them constantly loaded in memory, because I want to make my program as lightweight as I can.
I've tried nulling my objects, and it does null them, but now I can't RE-load them.
Here is the code:
    public void LoadPage(string URL)
    {
        if (URL != currentPage)
        {
            if (this.SystemRootIcon != null)
            {
                this.SystemRootIcon.Dispose();
            }
            if (URL == "Root")
            {
                if (this.SystemRootIcon == null)
                {
                    this.SystemRootIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
   // Below does not run
                    debug.Text = "RUNNING!";
                    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.SystemRootIcon)).BeginInit();
                    this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(this.SystemRootIcon);
                    this.SystemRootIcon.BackgroundImage = global::New_Control_Panel.Properties.Resources.imageres_195;
                    this.SystemRootIcon.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
                    this.SystemRootIcon.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 42);
                    this.SystemRootIcon.Name = "SystemRootIcon";
                    this.SystemRootIcon.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 48);
                    this.SystemRootIcon.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                    this.SystemRootIcon.TabIndex = 18;
                    this.SystemRootIcon.TabStop = false;
                    this.SystemRootIcon.Visible = true;
                    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.SystemRootIcon)).EndInit();
                }
                currentPage = URL;
            }
        }
    }


The title says: Can't null an object [...], in the body you state: I've tried nulling my objects, and it does null them [...]. The title should probably How to recreate an object [...], but that means you have to explain what objects you're talking about

Yeah, you're right.

Those are Controls. You usually Dispose() of them (do not just set the instance to null, quite important). Then, when you need more instances, you new some. If this process continues, make your own factory

I will try that.

Didn't work, still not showing up.

Added code cause there could be something wrong

It looks like that code is taken from the .designer.cs file. Not that it matters much, but it's not clear what calls LoadPage() and when it's called. Are you swapping Panel Containers in a, say, dashboard? Did you put a breakpoint in that method to see what parts are executed? -- It also looks like you're used to work with Web stuff. Don't assume a page (no such a term here, actually) is reloaded as a Web Page is

this.SystemRootIcon.Dispose(); does not set the value of SystemRootIcon to null, thus the later condition if (this.SystemRootIcon == null) will never be true. You need to set it to null explicitly after dispose.
Instead of testing for null, you could also test for IsDisposed instead. That might be a bit safer to do, since it does not involve null tests and therefore bears less risks of running into NullReferenceExceptions.
So the first condition should be something like:
            if (this.SystemRootIcon != null)
            {
                this.SystemRootIcon.Dispose();
                this.SystemRootIcon = null;
            }


Will try this to see if it works.

It turns out it was ALSO because of the way I was calling LoadPage();. Sorry for the troubles everyone.
